# Compilation errors showing up only locally (Angular)

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, angular5, package.json, npm-start

I am trying to run this application, but I keep getting this errors during compilation that I can't find a solution to. Normally I would know how to solve them but the real problem is that these errors are showing uonly on my PC. I am running the same exact code as some colleagues, using the same version of node, and onli I am getting these errors when trying npm start.

**The errors**
[image]

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "project",
"version": "1.0.0",
"license": "https://themeforest.net/licenses/terms/regular",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "start-hmr": "ng serve --hmr -e=hmr -sm=false",
    "start-hmr-sourcemaps": "ng serve --hmr -e=hmr",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev",
    "build-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev --stats-json",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
    "build-prod-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --stats-json",
    "prod": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng  build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "b": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --environment=svil --output-hashing=all --base-href ./",
    "s": "scp -r dist/* root@dev.division5.co:/var/www/html/Biglietteria5",
    "ci": "npm run b && npm run s"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.3",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.3",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.2.2",
    "@ctrl/ngx-codemirror": "^1.3.8",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^1.5.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "5.0.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "5.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^5.0.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "5.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "@nomadreservations/ngx-codemirror": "^2.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "7.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "11.1.7",
    "@swimlane/ngx-dnd": "3.1.0",
    "@types/prismjs": "1.9.0",
    "angular-calendar": "0.23.3",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.5.3",
    "angular-notifier": "^6.0.1",
    "angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "codemirror": "^5.39.2",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
    "core-js": "2.5.3",
    "d3": "4.13.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.9.0",
    "detect-browser": "^4.8.0",
    "fabric": "^2.4.3",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "fontfaceobserver-es": "^3.3.1",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "keycloak-angular": "^2.1.0",
    "keycloak-js": "^4.8.3",
    "moment": "2.20.1",
    "ng-modal-lib": "0.0.6",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^5.0.0",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "^5.3.1",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng5-slider": "^1.2.4",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "0.2.1",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "5.3.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-drag-drop": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-export-as": "^1.3.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.8.4",
    "ngx-mask": "^7.3.3",
    "ngx-pagination": "^4.0.0",
    "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-virtual-scroller": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-web-worker": "0.0.2",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.3.0",
    "print-js": "^1.0.54",
    "prismjs": "1.11.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.6",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.2",
    "text-mask-addons": "^3.8.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "5.2.3",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "2.1.3",
    "@types/codemirror": "0.0.58",
    "@types/google.analytics": "^0.0.42",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.15",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "6.0.96",
    "codelyzer": "4.1.0",
    "increase-memory-limit": "^1.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.4.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "4.1.0",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.10.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete your cache and install + compile everything from scratch?

Comment: any way to manually delete the cache? 'ng ' is not recognized, and yes I have tried starting from scratch.

Comment: If you did not delete the cache, you did not start "from scratch", as this belongs together.
Remove it via `rm -Rf node_modules/.cache`, or the entire `node_modules` altogether. Afterwards run `npm|yarn|pnpm install`, depending on what package manager you use.

Comment: I am using Windows

Comment: And Windows does not come with a file system?

Comment: the commands you used are Linux based commands, and I've already tried deleting manually and re-installing everything.

Answer (score 0):

Update your angular CLI

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

then clear angular cache and try again

Comment: do you say this because it's currently on Angular5? Because in that case I can't change the version, would only bring about more problems. Also, it gives me ''ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command'